# Create moment js object from date-time string and an offset

Tags: momentjs, utc, timezone-offset

I'm using Moment.js and have been all over the docs trying to find the best way, if any, to instantiate a moment object from a local date string and an offset, when I need that object to be in UTC and reflect said offset in its hours. For example:

if I have that somewhere it's January 1st, 2019 midnight, and that somewhere's offset is **-300**, that would be `2019:01:01T00:00:00.000-05:00`, right?, meaning it's 5 hours before UTC, so I need to be able to represent that in UTC like

`moment.utc("2019-01-01T05:00:00.000+00:00")`

What functions/transformations should I use for this purpose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are after this

```
moment.utc("2019-01-01 00:00:00").utcOffset(-300).format('YYYYMMDD HHmmss ZZ')
```

Note that the offset should be a number and not a string.

Comment: I've tried that, and that corresponds to ***December 31st, 2018 19:00:00 with offset -5*** (also ***January 1st, 2019 00:00:00 with offset 0 (UTC))***, and yields a timestamp of **1546300800000** milliseconds. What I need is a moment object which, for my example, corresponds to ***January 1st, 2019 05:00:00 with offset 0 (UTC)***, and yields a timestamp of **1546318800000** milliseconds.